# Handle a RFID from Delphi Application R/W

Tags: delphi, usb, rfid

I need to read/write cards using a RFID Reader
more specifically this:

https://www.parallax.com/product/28440

I am not very clear about how to do this since it is my first time with hardware devices connected to the USB port.

I find out there is a TComPort library, I allready installed it on my Delphi Berlin 10.1

From the parallax documentation I found this:

> Serial Communication (9600 baud default) Timeout is 100ms
>
> Write to RFID card:
>
> Send ASCII character 'w' to initiate write mode.
>
> Device will respond with 0x01 and will expect 4 bytes of data in return which will be the information entered in 
>    the 'Membership Year' Text box.
>
> Device will respond with 0x02 and will expect 4 bytes of data in return which will be the information entered in 
>    the 'Membership ID' Text box.
>
> Read:
>
> Send ASCII character 'r' to initiate read mode.
>
> Device will send 4 bytes of data (send to Card ID text box) and wait for a 0x01 response.
>    Device will send a further 4 bytes of data (Membership Year), and wait for a 0x01 response.
>    Device will send a final 4 bytes of data (Membership ID Number)

The question here is, how can I perfom these actions to write/read using the TComPort component?

Comment: The comport library includes a sample application. Open the sample project in your IDE and start to change it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Windows' `CreateFile` call you're able to connect to a connected USB device directly. All you need is the full, correct 'port name', see the `GetPortName` method [here](https://gist.github.com/stijnsanders/6fa64b44234b26a68b7269bf1a00c6f5#file-smartport-pas-L200)